# How to use private repository with initContainer

Tags: kubernetes, containers

I am able to use a imagePullSecret in my spec so that my container section images are able to connect to a private repository.   If I have initContainer section also, it is not using the imagePullSecret and the deployment fails.

Answer (score 3):

ImagePullSecret will work for both normal container and initContainer, you just need to define imagePullSecret once in your spec.

Comment: I am using 1.8.11 and it is not working.  I will try with a newer version.

Comment: ok，I'm using v1.10.3. and look at this: `https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/70732`, was that submitted by you?

Comment: Yes.  I submitted that one.